# How to Facebook Friends Leaderboard with Firebase?

Tags: facebook

I'm working on for a while about firebase and facebook friends leaderboard. How can I make a score system that will show scoreboard to all of the friends on facebook with firebase? I couldn't find any resources about it. I wonder if anyone can help me?

Comment: Facebook does not provide a scoring API any more - they used to, but this has been removed since. So if you want something like that, you will have to build it yourself on your end.

Comment: Can i make it with firebase or playfab or gamespark ?

Comment: you can make whatever you want with any database...so the answer would be as simple as "yes, you can".

Comment: what is the cause of this egoism ? Just want help !